# What does getLastKnownLocation really do?

Tags: android, location

Does it give the user's current location if the device is online? How does it determine the last known location?

Comment: Which device are you talking about?

Comment: i am sorry.. i meant getLastKnownLocation on Android devices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[LocationManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#getLastKnownLocation%28java.lang.String%29) docs

Taken from the docs & reworded
`getLastKnownLocation` returns the last known location fix obtained from the given provider.
The device does not need to start a provider to get this information so good for battery life.

However, if the users phone has been sleeping or turned off and has moved the location will be out-of-date.

If you need the location to be up-to-date I wouldn't use this method, instead request a single update, depending on your applications requirements.

Note: requesting location updates from an available provider will effect the users battery life if used irresponsibly

Comment: So from what I understand, if there is no application on the device that uses the location provider, the getLastKnownLocation will not have any data in it?

Comment: If no last known location is available it will return null unless it can get a fix within a reasonable amount of time.

Comment: would you have a source for this? would like to read more about it

Comment: You'll find plenty of examples on the web with a simple search, this is a pretty good example: http://marakana.com/forums/android/examples/42.html